# Exclude a field from search results by another field on elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have to delete a field from search results in Elasticsearch.  I want to remove the `detail` property if `display_detail` is False.

the documents example :

```
{
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "bella",
    "detail" : "descript their hobby",
    "display_detail" : true
},
{
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "michelle",
    "detail" : "another hobby",
    "display_detail" : false
}
```

this is the query looks like :

```
indexname=indexname
query = {
         "query_string" : {
              "query" : anna,
              "fields: : ["first_name","last_name"]
          }

}
results = es.search(index=indexname, query=query , source = ["first_name","last_name","detail"])
```

what I expect:

```
{
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "bella",
    "detail" : "descript their hobby",
},
{
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "michelle",
}
```

I can get the results above after get the search results like this :

```
for element in results['hits']['hits']: 
    if element["display_detail"] == "true":
        del element['detail'] 
    json.append(element)
```

is this a good way to deal with it? or is there any chance I can get the faster/cleanest way by using elastic query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to select/hide fields on a condition based.

However you can select/hide fields using [fields options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) or [source options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) from all the documents

**It's always recommended to handle such micro operations on the client end the same way you handled.**

Comment: ok thank you to clarify this problem.

Comment: Mark it solved if you find value in answer. So that it could help to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dicts then you can remove items from the dicts with pop.

Here is how to do it:

```py
ld = [
    {
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "bella",
    "detail" : "descript their hobby",
    "display_detail" : True
    },
    {
    "last_name" : "anna",
    "first_name" : "michelle",
    "detail" : "another hobby",
    "display_detail" : False
    }
]

print('before removing:')
print(ld)


for i in ld:
    if i['display_detail']==False:
        i.pop('detail')

print('after removing:')
print(ld)
```

And here is the result:

```
before removing:
[{'last_name': 'anna', 'first_name': 'bella', 'detail': 'descript their hobby', 'display_detail': True}, {'last_name': 'anna', 'first_name': 'michelle', 'detail': 'another hobby', 'display_detail': False}]
after removing:
[{'last_name': 'anna', 'first_name': 'bella', 'detail': 'descript their hobby', 'display_detail': True}, {'last_name': 'anna', 'first_name': 'michelle', 'display_detail': False}]
```

Comment: I am not removing "display_detail" fields. instead remove 'detail' fields if "display_detail" is false.

Comment: okay, this was just as easy to do with one additional `if` statement inside the loop. I have modified the answer accordingly so satify the question.